# How to return all values of an array

Tags: php

I am trying to return all the values of array but this code is acting as as a `die` statement..so what's the error in this code?

```
<?php 

$search_array = array("first"=> "first_user", 'second' => 4_user);
foreach($search_array as $key => $value ) 
{
    if(array_key_exists($key, $search_array))    
    {
        return $search_array[$key]; 
    } 
    else
    {       
        echo "not found"; 
    } 
}

?>
```

Comment: What is 4_user? or you is "4_user" using quotes.??

Comment: 4_user is just taken for  an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using `return` from within your loop, which will end the execution of the current scope.

If you want to return all values of that array, you need to push each value to a temporary storage variable and return that at the end of the loop:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
    $output[] = $value;
}
return $output;
```

---

That's for *your problem*. If all you want to do is return the values of an array, you can simply `return array_values($search_array)`. What you're trying to do is a tautological way of doing what this function does already.

Comment: OK fine but it's acting like a die statement and preventing other scripts below from being executed

Comment: Yes, don't return from the global scope like that